# compile error for arguments in object initialization

Tags: java, types, constructor, arguments

I have an object of class element:

```
public class Element {

   public int key;
   public Object data;

   public Element(int i, Object o){
      this.key = i;
      this.data = o;
   }
}
```

When I use:

```
public Element extractMin (){
    Element max = new Element( i, o );
    return max;
```

I get error:

```
PQHeap.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
        Element max = new Element( i, o );
                               ^
  symbol:   variable i
  location: class PQHeap
PQHeap.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
        Element max = new Element( i, o );
                                  ^
  symbol:   variable o
  location: class PQHeap
2 errors
```

When I define both types to arguments, "int" and "Object", during "max" initialization:

```
public Element extractMin (){
    Element max = new Element(int i, Object o );
    return max;
```

I get error:

```
PQHeap.java:46: error: '.class' expected
    Element max = new Element( int i, Object o );
                                   ^
PQHeap.java:46: error: ';' expected
    Element max = new Element( int i, Object o );
                                            ^
PQHeap.java:46: error: not a statement
    Element max = new Element( int i, Object o );
                                             ^
PQHeap.java:46: error: ';' expected
    Element max = new Element( int i, Object o );
```

What causes the errors and how do I define arguments correctly within initialization?

Thanks

Comment: Remove the `int` and the `Object` from the method invocation, and declare them as variables (or parameters, or fields).

Comment: You need to define and initialize `i` and `o` before using them as arguments. `new Element(i,o)` does not mean anything if `i` and `o` don't exist. Furthermore, they do not have to be called `i` and `o` just because they are called that in the parameter definition.

Comment: What Andy said, plus, where do you expect `i` and `o` to come from ? these variables are not in your scope... And please please please do *not* name variables `i` and `o`...

Comment: When I remove types, I get error 1 shown above. I guess i and o are already initialized within class above. Please correct me if I'm wrong on that. I know that they don't have to be called the same, I used those names for the sake of convinience. Naming them that doesn't really change anything

Comment: But thanks with clarifying error 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you assign i and o first?

```
int i = 7;
Object o = {[object here]};
public Element extractMin ()
{
    Element max = new Element( i, o );
    return max;
}
```

Comment: values are assigned to the initialized i and o through an input method defined in another class

Comment: that class gets input values i and o and calls PQHeap.extractMin() to initialize "max" object of type/class Element. Might that cause a problem?

Comment: You are right Tracy: I didn't define values for "max" object. The input values went to another object of the same class Element, but "max" was not assigned when called. Thanks